# Facebook Canvas App not loading my URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I got a page at www.somedomain.com/facebook/index.html http://www.somedomain.com/facebook/index.html. I'd like to serve that via the apps...so via the canvas but when I point the canvas url to this directory (www.somedomain.com/facebook/) I get a page not found error on the apps page. However, hitting www.somedomain.com/facebook/ http://www.somedomain.com/facebook/ does serve index.html in a browser. Any clues as to what's going on here? Might add...there is no https page setup as yet. This is just a static HTML page that I'd like to serve via apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to load your page inside the canvas iframe, Facebook is issuing an HTTP POST request for the URL http://www.somedomain.com/facebook/index.html.

My guess is your server only serves pages requested using GET.